# Json Parsing Error: use of undeclared type 'Foundation' in Swift iOS

Tags: ios, json, swift, parsing, jsonparser

I am creating an app using Swift, where I have to display a list of Countries using below URL:

> https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all

Here I have to fetch only `name` key and add to my `NSMutableArray`.  When I am trying to parse this using URLSession, I am getting error :

```
expression produced error: error: /var/folders/_3/27lhgzw9699c4_yg37r72_d80000gp/T/expr40-bcf47d..swift:1:65: error: use of undeclared type 'Foundation'
Swift._DebuggerSupport.stringForPrintObject(Swift.UnsafePointer<Foundation.Data>(bitPattern: 0x105c0c2f0)!.pointee)
```

Below is my code:

```
func fetchCountryList(countryURL:URL, completion:@escaping (NSDictionary) -> ()) {

            print(countryURL)

            let request = NSMutableURLRequest( url: countryURL as URL)

            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
                data, response, error in
                do{
                    if let data = data,
                        let jsonString =  try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
                        , error == nil {
                        completion(jsonString)
                    } else {
                        print("error=\(error!.localizedDescription)")
                        let errorDict = ["error_status":true,"message":error!.localizedDescription] as [String : Any]
                        completion(errorDict as NSDictionary)

                    }
                }
                catch{
                    print("error=\(error.localizedDescription)")
                    let errorDict = ["error_status":true,"message":error.localizedDescription] as [String : Any]
                    completion(errorDict as NSDictionary)

                }

            }
            task.resume()
    }
```

Can anyone please suggest me my mistake here. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Do not use `NSDictionary` in Swift. Use a proper Swift dictionary. Do not use `NSMutableURLRequest` in Swift. Use `URLRequest`. Do not use the `.mutableContainers` option in Swift (once you switch to Swift dictionary).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
 let jsonString =  try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
```

with

```
if let result =  try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options:[]) as? [[String:Any]] {
   for item in result {
     print(item["name"])
   }  
 }
```

the response is array not dictionary also don't use NS stuff

> NSDictionary => [String:Any]
>
> NSUrl => URL
>
> NSMutableURLRequest => URLRequest

---

```
func fetchCountryList(countryURL:URL, completion:@escaping (_ arr :[[String:Any]]?, _ error:Error?) -> ()) {
        
            print(countryURL)
        
            let request = URLRequest( url: countryURL)

            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {
                data, response, error in
                do{
                    if let data = data,
                        let jsonString =  try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options:[]) as? [[String:Any]]
                        , error == nil {
                        completion(jsonString,nil)
                    } else {
                        print("error=\(error!.localizedDescription)")
                        let errorDict = ["error_status":true,"message":error!.localizedDescription] as [String : Any]
                        completion(nil,error)
                        
                    }
                }
                catch{
                    print("error=\(error.localizedDescription)")
                    let errorDict = ["error_status":true,"message":error.localizedDescription] as [String : Any]
                    completion(nil,error)
                    
                }
                
            }
            task.resume()
    }
```

---

Call

```
serviceModel.fetchCountryList(countryURL:countryURL){ (result,error) in 
  if let res = result {
    print(res)
  } 
}
```

Comment: Hi @Sh_Khan, Thanks for your response, after replace I am getting error : Cannot convert value of type '[[String : Any]]' to expected argument type 'NSDictionary' in this line : completion(jsonString)

Comment: I think no need to status as you don't handle status **false** so i omitted it and returned only the error see edit

Comment: Okay, I am calling this method like :let serviceModel = ServiceModel()
            
            serviceModel.fetchCountryList(countryURL:countryURL){
                responsStr in

Comment: Can you please help me to call this method in order to get two Completion?

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
```

With

```
try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as? [[String: Any]]
```

Since it's an array of objects, we also need to cast the json as an `array`

For getting an `array of country names`, we can do this by:

```
guard let countries = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as? [[String: Any]] else {
    return
}
let countryNames = countries.map { $0["name"] as! String }
```

Comment: There is no need to use `.mutableContainers` with a Swift collection.

Comment: Just reuse his code & change a little to help him understand simpler w/ few changes. By the way, thanks for the suggestion @rmaddy.